# C++ to webassembly run using Emscripten and run it in Deno

Tags: emscripten, deno

I was trying to run a hello world program written in C++, converted it to .wasm file (using Emscripten) and trying to run it in Deno as a webassembly module.
But getting error: `error: Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Here is my cpp code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello world!"<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Which I convert to wasm using `em++ hello.cpp -o hello.js`.

Here is my ts code:

```
export {}

import * as hello from  './hello.js';

hello._main();
```

I googled a lot but as such there is no example any where on internet, where a C++ program converted via Emscripten is made to run in Deno.
All docs will say that Emscripten can do it, but none shows how!?

Do any one has been able to run webassembly code converted from C++ [oh yes rust has many examples], via Emscripten to run on Deno ?

Comment: What does it look like in `hello.js`?

Comment: @RevelMind Its a long file ~500 lines of code, auto creted by the emscripten

Comment: I would recommend you go on the deno discord channel and ask them directly regarding this.